# How to add an if statement to determine if you are on a specific route?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, routes

I could not find an answer to this anywhere. What I am trying to do is to get a different CSS depending on what route you are on. So e.g.

```
<% if root_path %>
```

What is the code for that?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Depending on the route, a different view would be rendered, and hence you can write your CSS accordingly to be 'namespaced' such that they affect only those pages that they should.

Comment: Well, I know that, but what if you wanted to put some of your code in the layout? I know that you can just do a layout change, but that might be too complex if you just can find the route.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [`current_page?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F) helper it is very handy for case like this.

```
current_page?(action: 'process')
# => false
current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout')
# => true
current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout', order: 'asc')
# => false
current_page?(action: 'checkout')
# => true
current_page?(controller: 'library', action: 'checkout')
# => false
current_page?('http://www.example.com/shop/checkout')
# => true
current_page?('/shop/checkout')
# => true
```

and i doesn't tested but this should work to:

```
if current_page?(product_path(@product))
  #some logic here
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to since you can set up your CSS such that each view pulls different CSS values.

However, if you really want to you can take advantage of the params hash Rails passes to every view that includes the controller and the action.

```
<%= params %>
#{"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
<% if params[:controller] == "home" and params[:action] == "index" %>
  #dothings
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a dynamic class on the `body` element and then bind to it in my CSS / SASS like so:

```
<body class="#{controller.action_name}">...</body>
```

then for the index page, the body class would be `.index`, and in your SASS you can do things like

```
body.index { ... }
```